# Twitter Typeahead Suggestion Limit

Tags: typeahead.js

I'm using the latest version of Typeahead (0.10.2) and I can't get the plugin to give me more than 139 records.  When I change the query to return 140 records then I get the "empty" template I created.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
  name: "courses",
  limit: 5000,
  prefetch: { url: "../../CFC/XXX.cfc?term=aa&returnformat=json",
              ajax: { dataType: "json", 
                      cache: false,
                      data:{ method: "Search" } 
                    }
  },
  remote: { url: "../../CFC/XXX.cfc?term=%QUERY&returnformat=json",
            ajax: { dataType: "json", 
                    cache: false,
                    data:{ method: "Search",
                    timeout: 5000 }
                  }
  },
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value); },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});

$("#Source").typeahead({
   minLength: 2,
   highlight: true},
   {
    name: "courses",
    displayKey: "value",
    timeout: 1000,
    source: engine.ttAdapter(),
    engine: engine,
    templates: { empty: [ '<div class="empty-message">',
                          'Unable to find any courses that match your entry.',
                          '</div>'
                        ].join('\n')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a bug in the current version of typeahead.  110 is parsed to 10.  10 is parsed to 0.  10 records == 0!  Yay!